# AngularJS: Debounce. Fire changes to apply on click

Tags: angularjs

There are input with debounce, 'clear' btn (to clear input) and 'use' btn (to use input value). :

```
<input ng-model="*"  ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
```

For proper 'clear' btn work $rollbackViewValue() is used [(here)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)

```
<button ng-click='formname.$rollbackViewValue();vm.clear()' />
```

But what approach can be used for 'use' btn? How fire changes to apply on click (before debounce interval will be ended)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 'use btn' use `$commitViewValue()`

```
<button ng-click="userForm.userName.$commitViewValue(); setValue()">setValue</button>
```

Just example

```
<form name="userForm">
    <label>Name:
        <input type="text" name="userName"
            ng-model="user.name"
            ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />
    </label>
    <button ng-click="userForm.userName.$commitViewValue(); setValue()">setValue</button>

    <button ng-click="userForm.userName.$rollbackViewValue(); user.name=''">Clear</button>
    <br />
</form>
```

Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/EwaNsCcfa72sdnK3REgY?p=preview

Comment: Thx! **$commitViewValue()** is what i looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can be more specific with your model options:

```
<input ng-model="*"  ng-model-options="{ debounce: { 'default': 1000, 'blur': 0 } }" />
```

That way, when you click the button, the debounce timeout should be zero since you loose focus on the input element.

Comment: Thx a lot. Just one amendment : **ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 3000, 'blur': 0 } }"** have to be used.  And for proper 'clear' btn work  **$rollbackViewValue() is still needed**